# Vanilla tilt not working. no error on console

Tags: javascript

I am doing a glass morph card via dreaded tutorial(almost out of hell!). I have downloaded the Vanilla Tilt JS, added the script to my body, added query selector to my element but still nothing ?! My recent mistakes have been ridiculous and I have been over thinking everything therefore missing the simple! Please help !

```js
VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelector(".card"), {
  max: 25,
  speed: 400,
  glare: true,
  "max-glare": 1,

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.7.2/vanilla-tilt.min.js" integrity="sha512-K9tDZvc8nQXR1DMuT97sct9f40dilGp97vx7EXjswJA+/mKqJZ8vcZLifZDP+9t08osMLuiIjd4jZ0SM011Q+w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>02</h2>
    <h3>Tech Stuff</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur tenetur laborum repellendus maxime excepturi nisi enim? Perferendis est nulla explicabo?</p>
    <a href="#">Check it out</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>03</h2>
    <h3>Tech Stuff</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur tenetur laborum repellendus maxime excepturi nisi enim? Perferendis est nulla explicabo?</p>
    <a href="#">Check it out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It seems to work

Comment: If you need it to tilt BOTH you need `querySelectorAll`

Comment: I understand that, but not even the one is working, before I do all..

Comment: I see that. So why not on my machine :(

Comment: I cannot tell. no errors  in the console?

Comment: no , there are no console errors.

Comment: ive same problem..but why this work in any site editor code, but doesnt work in my browser or vscode?

Comment: where are you adding the JS code in your html? It should be at the end.